# My test site is not launching from Playwright automation when the browser is set to Desktop Chrome

Tags: chromium, playwright

I am trying to launch a website from Playwright, the browser is set to desktop chrome. But I am getting an error message saying the website is not reachable. I can able to launch the website manually and when I try to launch the site on other browsers like safari, Firefox or iPhone it is launching successfully from Playwright. Has anyone experienced similar issue. I have been trying solution for long time but I couldn't find anything useful. Kindly help me on this.

Thanks in advance!!

I am expecting the site to launch successfully from the Playwright using Desktop Chrome browser. Sometime the site is launching successfully but when I try to perform any actions the site is again unreachable

Comment: could you add a minimum working code so and errors, if any so that the issue can be analyzed.

Comment: test.use({
    headless: false,
      deviceScaleFactor: 2,
      launchOptions: {
        viewport: { width: 390, height: 844 },
        screenshot:"only-on-failure",
        slowMo: 100,
          
      },
  });

Comment: test.only('First Playwright test',async({browser}) =>
{
    
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    await context.tracing.start({ screenshots: true, snapshots: true });

    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto('testsite');

    await page.waitForLoadState('load');
    if(await page.isVisible('#popup-close'))
      await page.click('#popup-close');
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png', fullPage: true });
    await context.tracing.stop();
});

Comment: I can able to launch any site using the above code, only my test site is not working. I use multiple test sites for testing, there is one particular site which is not launching. My other team members are doesn't see this issue